# Can safe app be created as an iframe?

Tags: gnosis, safe-apps-sdk

I am thinking to add my [safe app](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-tools/sdks/safe-apps) as an iframe but not sure if it is possible and right way to continue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe Apps are embedded into the Safe wallet as an iframe, yes

Comment: Thanks for the response @mikheevm.